# How to send an image and display it in email using php instead of a url or attachment?

Tags: php

In writing a web srevice, how can i send image to email and display it.I am able to send email with all content except the image. I think there is some mistake in the image code . Can any one help me out with this ? my code is

```
<?php
$title=$_REQUEST['title'];
$location=$_REQUEST['location'];
$contactname=$_REQUEST['contactname'];
$contactnumber=$_REQUEST['contactnumber'];
$description=$_REQUEST['description'];
$image=$_REQUEST['image'];
if($title)
{
$Image=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$Image=str_replace(' ','|',$Image);
$date=date('YmdHis');
$date=str_replace('%20',' ',$date);
$Image=$date.".jpg";
$tmppath="images/".$Image;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$tmppath);
$message1 = ?><html><head></head><body>
<? $message1 .= ?><img src="http://www.website.com/appinstaller/ramaraju/images/<?= $Image ?>" /></body></html>
<?php
$headers = "From: support@";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//$mailimg = '<img src="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/ramaraju/services/images/$file"</a>';

 $to = "ramaraju.d@stellentsoft.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $message="Title : $title\r\n Location:$location\r\n Contact name:$contactname\r\n Contact:$contactnumber\r\n Description:$description\r\n file:$Image";



  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  {
  $message=array("messsage"=>"Message successfully sent!");
  } else {
  $message=array("message"=>"Message delivery failed.");
  }
  }
  else
  {
  $message=array("message"=>"provide values");
  }
  echo json_encode($message);



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do this `<?=$Image ?>` rather than `<? $Image ?>` as in your code in src you have not printed `$Image`..

Hence Final img tag should be

```
<img src="http://www.myappdemo.com/appinstaller/ramaraju/images/<?=$Image ?>" />
```

`<?` and `<?=` are called short open tags, and are not always enabled (see the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive)

Comment: Yes it worked with $message .='<html><head></head><body><img src=http://www.website.com/ramaraju/images/'.$Image.' /></body></html>';